# Retrieve List of Tables from Specific Database on Server C#

Tags: c#, sql

How can one retrieve the tables' names into a `List<string>` from a specific database on a server?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`System.Data.SqlClient` has what you need without a formal query on sys.Tables (though that's what it's using in the background). Use the `GetSchema()` method on the `SqlConnection` object and designate that you want the "Tables" and it will send you a `DataTable` object back with a row for each table. It sends back database name, table schema name, table name, and table type in each row (in that column order). The code would look like this:

```
public static List<string> GetTables(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
        List<string> TableNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
        {
            TableNames.Add(row[2].ToString());
        }
        return TableNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: The connection is wrapped in a using block, so the connection is closed once the code exits the block.

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server 2005 and higher:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=DB_Name;")) {
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText =
            @"SELECT s.name, o.name
            FROM sys.objects o WITH(NOLOCK)
            JOIN sys.schemas s WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
            WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND RTRIM(o.type) = 'U'
            ORDER BY s.name ASC, o.name ASC";

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                string schemaName = reader.GetString(0);
                string tableName = reader.GetString(1);

                // your code goes here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you have the SqlConnection already, why not use .GetSchema("Tables")?

Answer (score 3):

To fetch all the user defined tables from the DB ( SQlServer), we have to query system catalogs.

```
SELECT  Name from Sysobjects where xtype = 'u'
```

this query will return all the user defined tables in the *DataBase*

Answer (score 2):

I think that this SQL should return a table containing tableNames in your DB:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ query to get all tables name fairly easily:

```cs
public List<string> GetSqlTables(SqlConnection conn)
    => (from DataRow row in conn.GetSchema("Tables").Rows.Cast<DataRow>() 
        select row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core extension using `SqlConnection` that opens/closes the connection.

```
public static class SQLExtensions
{
    public static List<string> GetTableNames(this SqlConnection connection)
    {
        using (connection)
        {
            connection.Open();

            return connection.GetSchema("Tables")
                             .Rows
                             .Cast<DataRow>()
                             .Select(row => row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString())
                             .OrderBy(nme => nme)
                             .ToList();

        } // Auto Close exiting the block
    }
}
```

###### Usage (Linqpad)

```
var connectionStr = @"Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Rasa";

(new SqlConnection(connectionStr).GetTableNames()).Dump();
```

Answer (score -1):

this my solution:

```
    public void opencon()
    {
        if (conn == null)
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(@"Your connection");
        }
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
    }
    public void Closecon()
    {
        if ((conn != null) && (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open))
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
   public void GetTables(ComboBox cb)
    {
            chuoiketnoi();
            DataTable schema = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
            foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
            {
                cb.Items.Add(row[2].ToString());
            }
            dongketnoi();
    }
```

Comment: chuoiketnoi? dongketnoi?