# How can I count the number of tables in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

How can I make a code to get the number of tables to a link textbox in a given database? I'm using visual studio 2013 and  I'm new to this. I used database server  ms sql.

```
public static List<string> GetTables(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
        List<string> TableNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
        {
          TableNames.Add(row[0].ToString());
        }
        return TableNames;

    }

}
```

Comment: `Database_Name.information_schema.tables`

Comment: What is the problem of your code? Why is `schema.Rows.Count` not the answer to your question?

Comment: can you give me the count code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671067/retrieve-list-of-tables-from-specific-database-on-server-c-sharp

Comment: @sweatbar: yes, no problem: `int tableCount = schema.Rows.Count;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, i don't understand the question. You want the count of tables in a given database. The database is specified by the connection-string. You have already the code that returns a `DataTable` with all tables.

So here is the missing piece. Since `connection.GetSchema("Tables")` also returns views, if you want to count both you are ready with:

```
DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
int tableAndViewCount = schema.Rows.Count;
```

If you only want to count tables and exclude views:

```
int tableCount = schema.AsEnumerable().Count(t => t.Field<string>("TABLE_TYPE") == "BASE TABLE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

select * from sys.tables

Answer (score 0):

Get count of tables using the below query , just add that query in your application.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'base table'
```