# Why can I not get the names of my tables using System.Data.SqlClient?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design

I did not create and do not own this database. My job is usually just to put data in it, so I don't have to think too much about the DBA side. I am messing with a side project and can not figure out why I can't list all the table names. I have found several methods to gather this information, but none work for me in a c# context. I get 0 rows back every time. They do work when executed as queries in azure data studio. I get 99 rows back (the correct number of tables) no matter which method I use to enumerate the tables. My connection string specifies the database to use within the server.

The query named `workingQuery` returns the expected information (1 row with 15 fields). So I know my connection string is correct and my code is functional.

I have a test function that I am trying many queries on.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    List<string> fields = new List<string>();
    string workingQuery = "SELECT TOP (1) * FROM myRealTable";
    string failingTablesQuery1 = "SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U'";
    string failingTablesQuery2 = "SELECT name AS table_name FROM sys.tables GO";
    string failingTablesQuery3 = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'";

    using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = workingQuery;

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                fields.Add(reader[i].ToString());
            }
        conn.Close();
        return fields; 
    }
}
```

In addition to the raw sql queries I have also tried [SqlConnection.GetSchema("Tables")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6671427/8657981). It also returns no rows.

I tried prepending `USE myDatabaseName;` to the front of the queries to no effect.

I can only assume this is an issue with the way the database is set up. Can anyone help me track down what is causing this issue?

SOLUTION:
My connection string had credentials that did not have the necessary permissions for this operation.

Comment: You say/imply that they *aren't* working, but you don't tell us *why* they aren't working. What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I'll edit my question. Working was meant to say I get rows back. Not working was meant to say I get no rows back when I should.

Comment: I would think that the sys namespace would be relevant.  Somehow objects that are not user objects are not queryable the way your connection string or runtime is behaving.  I would put your sysobjects query in a view or stored proc - you would own the view or sp and then see if you can query it. (all of this a guess.)

Comment: Are you using the correct identity?  It's possible you lack VIEW DEFINITION permission on the objects.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This was my issue. I thought I was using the same permissions during my manual testing. However, I was actually using my personal credentials when manually testing instead of the production credentials. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, I put that in an awnser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server access to metadata is controlled by the VIEW DEFINITION permission.  You might have permission to SELECT from a table, but not to view its definition or discover it in the catalog.  By default any permission on an object implies VIEW DEFINITION, but it can be DENY'd to a user.  See [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?view=sql-server-ver15).

So check that you're using the same identity in both places and that that identity has VIEW DEFINITION permissions on the tables.